# Hide AWS Cogniton User Pool Client Id/Secret in Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am building an Android application in Java and using the **Cognito User Pool** [( demo)](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo) to generate **User Session Tokens** to authenticate the Rest Api calls.

In the  [demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo)  the client secret is written in the the AppHelper class.

So, my question is : Is it safe to keep the client Id and Client Secret in the open.
If not , what is the best way to do it.?

If hacker will decompile they can see the keys right? HOw can I protect my app.

Please, give me suggesstions.
Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916034/what-is-a-cognito-app-client-secret